# closing a box with mousehover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this box. I want this box to open when I hover my mouse over the part that is still visible. Now when I hover my mouse nothing happens. I think the error must be the JS file. Calling the function goes okay because if put for example an

```
alert("test")
```

in the close box function everything works except the box.

HTML:

```
<div class="box" onmouseover="boxclose();">
  <h4 class="AlarmHeader"> Alarm Times!</h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  height: 150px; width: 400px;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-100px;
  right:5px;
```

JS:

```
function boxclose() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.bottom="0px"
}
```

Useful link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp

Comment: what is your actual requirement ???

Comment: I would love to have that is close standard, but if you hover your mouse over it will rise/open so the content in the box can be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getElementsByClassName`, which returns a list instead of one element, so you just need to tell it which element to target:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.bottom="0px"
```

Working example:

```js
function boxclose() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.bottom="0px"
}
```

```css
.box{
height: 150px; width: 400px;
background-color:black;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
padding: 5px;
position:fixed;
bottom:-100px;
right:5px;
```

```html
<div class="box" onmouseover="boxclose();">
  <h4 class="AlarmHeader"> Alarm Times!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: you fixed the problem! How did you find out it was a List? so I can look it up myself.

Comment: @AntonvanderWel When you're using DOM selectors like that, there's basically two kinds: those that return a single element (like `.getElementById` or `.querySelector`) and those that return a list of nodes. Any of them that have "elements" as part of the method name will return a list of nodes: `.getElementsByClassName`, `.getElementsByTagName`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need javascript there, you can do that with css, too i will add a transition, try the following:

```css
.box{
height: 150px; width: 400px;
background-color:black;
border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
padding: 5px;
position:fixed;
bottom:-100px;
right:5px;
transition:all .8s cubic-bezier(1,.65,1,.61);
}
.box:hover {
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4 class="AlarmHeader"> Alarm Times!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok brother, no problem

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong changing your js file like this will work,

```
function boxclose() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.bottom="0px"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello If i Properly understand you then please try this.

```css
.box-popup {padding: 5px 10px; border:1px solid #ddd; position:relative;}
.box-popup span {display: none;}
.box-popup:hover span {display: block; padding: 10px; width: 200px; height: 100px; border:1px solid #eee; position: absolute; left:0; top: 30px;}
```

```html
<div class="box-popup">
  Hover
  <span>
    Hover Data
  </span>
</div>
```